# The term for a variable in a conditional

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology, conditional-statements

In the following statement what is the term to refer to the `$country` operand? Could it be `the evaluated variable`?

```
if($country == "Bulgaria"){}
```

Comment: "Left hand operand in a comparison expression"…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a language-agnostic term for it.

It could be an expression, an operand, a variable ...

Answer (score 2):

There's no special name for any of the operands, they are completely equal from the language standpoint. You just compare something to something, each "something" can be a variable or not.